# Libraries setup using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project folder MultiViewReconstruction and it has three subfolders STM, V3D, Visualization.

```
-MultiViewReconstruction
   -STM
   -V3D
   -Visualization
```

CMakeLists.txt inside MultiViewReconstruction is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(MultiViewReconstruction)
# The version number.
set (VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (VERSION_MINOR 0)
# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# should we use our own math functions?
option (FILES 
        "Use tutorial provided math implementation" ON) 
option (VIDEO 
        "Use tutorial provided math implementation" OFF)
option (CAMERA 
        "Use tutorial provided math implementation" OFF)  
# to the source code
configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Config.h"
)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

# Linked libariries
#For Opencv
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
#For PCL
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
#Additional libraries
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/STM")
add_subdirectory (STM)
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Visualization")
add_subdirectory (Visualization)
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/V3D")
add_subdirectory (V3D)

set (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} STM  Visualization V3D)


ADD_EXECUTABLE(MultiViewReconstruction MultiViewReconstruction.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MultiViewReconstruction ${OpenCV_LIBS}; ${PCL_LIBRARIES}; ${EXTRA_LIBS}; pthread)

# add the install targets
install (TARGETS MultiViewReconstruction DESTINATION bin)
install (FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Config.h" DESTINATION include)
```

CMakeLists.txt inside STM is

```
add_library(STM STM.cpp FeatureMatching.cpp Triangulation.cpp Common.cpp BundleAdjuster.cpp)

install (TARGETS STM DESTINATION bin)
install (FILES STM.h FeatureMatching.h Triangulation.h Common.h BundleAdjuster.h DESTINATION include)
```

CMakeLists.txt inside Visualization is

```
add_library(Visualization Visualization.cpp)
install (TARGETS Visualization DESTINATION bin)
install (FILES Visualization.h DESTINATION include)
```

CMakeLists.txt inside V3D is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(V3D)

set (V3D_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set (V3D_INCLUDE_DIRS ${V3D_DIR}/.)

include (Config/v3d_macros.cmake)

include (Config/local_config.cmake)


file(   GLOB COLAMD_SRC 
    COLAMD/Source/* 
    COLAMD/Include/* 
    SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.h 
    SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c
    )
include_directories("SuiteSparse_config/")
add_library(colamd ${COLAMD_SRC})
set ( V3D_INCLUDE_DIRS ${V3D_INCLUDE_DIRS} "COLAMD/Include" )



include_directories(${V3D_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EXTRA_INC_DIRS})


source_group("Base" REGULAR_EXPRESSION Base/.*cpp|Base.*h)
set (BASE_SRC
    Base/v3d_exception.h
    Base/v3d_serialization.h
    Base/v3d_vrmlio.h
)
if (V3DLIB_ENABLE_SOCKETS)
    set (BASE_SRC ${BASE_SRC} Base/v3d_socket.h)
endif (V3DLIB_ENABLE_SOCKETS)

source_group("Math" REGULAR_EXPRESSION Math/.*cpp|Math.*h)
set (MATH_SRC
    Math/v3d_linear.h
    Math/v3d_linearbase.h
    Math/v3d_mathutilities.h
    Math/v3d_nonlinlsq.h
    Math/v3d_nonlinlsq.cpp
    Math/v3d_optimization.h
    Math/v3d_optimization.cpp
    Math/v3d_optimization_lm.cpp
)

source_group("Geometry" REGULAR_EXPRESSION Geometry/.*cpp|Geometry.*h)
set (GEOMETRY_SRC
    Geometry/v3d_cameramatrix.h
    Geometry/v3d_distortion.h
    Geometry/v3d_metricbundle.h
    Geometry/v3d_metricbundle.cpp
    Geometry/v3d_stereobundle.h
    Geometry/v3d_stereobundle.cpp
)

set (ALL_SRC
    ${BASE_SRC} ${MATH_SRC} ${GEOMETRY_SRC} ${GL_SRC} ${CUDA_SRC}
)

add_library(V3D ${ALL_SRC})
add_subdirectory(Apps)
```

When I build, I have error as

```
In file included from /home/Softwares/3D_images/MultiViewReconstruction/STM/BundleAdjuster.cpp:44:0:
/home/Softwares/3D_images/MultiViewReconstruction/STM/../V3D/Math/v3d_linear.h:6:33: fatal error: Math/v3d_linearbase.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Math/v3d_linearbase.h"
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [STM/CMakeFiles/STM.dir/BundleAdjuster.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [STM/CMakeFiles/STM.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

EDIT:

```
BundleAdjuster.cpp has
#include "../V3D/Math/v3d_linear.h"


v3d_linear.h has
#include "Math/v3d_linearbase.h"
v3d_linear.h and v3d_linearbase.h are in the same Math folder.
```

But can't find each other

Where do I make mistakes in linking libraries?

Thanks

Comment: the problem is not in linking the libraries. He says he can't find "Math/v3d_linearbase.h"; so just make sure that you use `include_directories` with the path to where he can find those headers.

Comment: @ChrisMaes I added EDIT. They are in the same folder, but can't find each other. Where do I make mistake?

Comment: Including by path `Math/v3d_linearbase.h`requires `include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/V3D")` to be in effect. You have this command in your *CMakeLists.txt*, but it is located **after** `add_subdirectory(STM)`, so it doesn't affect on *STM/CMakeLists.txt*, where you build your library.

Comment: Alternatively just use #include "v3d_linearbase.h", since they are in the same folder.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, it works